# Arabic name query returns more then one results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, arabic

I have a situation when doing a simple select query with a specific arabic name like the following "رفعة" the query returns more then one results. It rightly returns "رفعة", but it also returns "رفعت".

```
SELECT * FROM Table where ArabicName = N'رفعة'
```

I have encountered two other situations as well. When querying with "حياة" it returns "حياة" and "حيات".
When querying with "نعمة" it returns "نعمة" and "نعمت".

I have searched online for answers, but without luck.

Has anyone encountered this situation before?

Comment: Likely it's the collation; what collation  are you using?

Comment: We are using the following collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the following to the query: `COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AS`

```
SELECT * FROM Table where ArabicName COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AS = N'رفعة'
```

Nb! It did not work without specifying the `_100_` in the collation specification.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to collation and you should understand what that means especially last few letters in collation `Arabic_100_CI_AS`.

`CI` means case insensitive, also you have option to set `CS` which means case sensitive

`AS` means accent sensitive, same as case there is option `AI` which means accent insensitive

Well, this collation can be set on server, database, column level or you can explicitly search adding `COLLATE` command at the end of statement.

Comment: Thanks Emin. Without adding the ´_100_´ in the collation, it did not work.So if I added the following it would not work: ´Arabic_CI_AS´. Also I read that collation can not be set for an entire table, but not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @Örvar you are right, but when you are creating table you can explicitly set different collations for different columns. I have removed columns from answer so as not to confuse others.